# Magento2 ajaxsuite- ajax login

Tags: magento-2.1, cart, login, ajax, shopping-cart

I want to show Ajax suit modules, Ajax login popup on cart page when press checkout button. right now, I used

```
 $('.modals-wrapper .popup-authentication').addClass("_show")
```

and it shows magento2 default popup login modal. but i want to change it to Ajax suit login popup.

Can any body guide me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a global class on login.phtml, then add below code into Magento_Checkout, form.phtml

```
$('.global-login').click();
```

Comment: Hi, can you please be more clear. Actually i want the same.